# D3.js wrap text in rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like for rectangle to wrap my text. But width and height are returned as zero. Funny thing is if I don't use any function(d) {} and insert literals instead, this code works perfectly.

```
var nodes_enter = nodes.enter()
    .append('g');
var rect = nodes_enter.append("rect")
    .style('fill', function(d) {return d.tag_color_background;});
var text = nodes_enter.append('text')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', -50)
    .text(function(d) {return d.tag_text;});
// width and heaight returns 0 :(
rect.attr('width', text.node().getBBox().width)
    .attr('height', text.node().getBBox().height);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle? It seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLg52283/ (I changed the `x` and `y` attributes of the `text` node to make it visible).

Comment: Weird, I can not reproduce it. I'm doing update via ajax so my code is much more perplexed than this. But it all boils down to my example or so I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getBBox().width return 0 the text node probably has no value.

By the way: the variable `text` is an array of selected elements. So `text.node()` will only return the first selected text node and thus it's dimensions are applied to all rects. Imagine a small text first and another longer one. With your code, the longer one get a background rect with the small dimensions.

Here is a suggestion:

```
nodes_enter.each(function() {
    var w = this.getBBox().width,
        h = this.getBBox().height;
    d3.select(this).select('rect').attr({'width': w, 'height': h});
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/vLg52283/3/)

Comment: Ok, but the problem is this refers to the g element. I have many text elements and rect elements in one g (which is a link). I've solved the rect addressing with class selector. How would I loop over texts and not over gs?

Comment: made some changes: http://jsfiddle.net/hsomyge9/
if you have more rects and texts in the same g element, just put some classes on them and select accordingly.